# How to get message and error code from SHOW ERROR MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL 5.5 and I use `SHOW ERRORS` for detect the error from my stored procedure. But I need to get the message from `SHOW ERRORS` results to be inserted to my log table. How can I do it,.?
The `SHOW ERRORS` result is like this:

```
Level     Code     Message
========================================================
Error     1146     Table 'mysql.my_table' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL would have TRY-CATCH clause, then you could catch an error and write information about it.

I'd suggest you to do it in application level - catch the error and write information into log file/table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this in 5.5, however if you've updated to 5.6+ you can do the following:

I have used [GET DIAGNOSTICS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html) to gain access to the error information and then use these as input for inserts to error logs.

Create structures for example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_that_exists 
(
column_that_exists INT(11) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (column_that_exists)
);
    
CREATE TABLE tbl_error_log 
(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, err_no INT(4)
, err_msg VARCHAR(50)
, source_proc VARCHAR(50)
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Run query to produce an error & show output of SHOW_ERRORS:

```
SELECT anything FROM table_that_exists;

SHOW ERRORS;
```

Example of how to access data for use in other procedures/error management:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
@P1 = MYSQL_ERRNO, @P2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;

SELECT @P1, @P2;

INSERT INTO tbl_error_log (err_no, err_msg, source_proc)
VALUES (@P1, @P2, 'sp_faulty_procedure');

SELECT * FROM tbl_error_log;
```